# How to pass variable from one class to another class?

Tags: java, for-loop, variables

I am currently working on my semester assignment. I'm designing a food ordering system, which allows the user to order food and drink by himself.

I'm having two classes which one of them is for ordering food then another one is ordering drinks.
Now, the problem I can't pass the food total amount which is the pay variable below onto the ordering drink class to calculate the whole amount. So, I'm wondering is it possible to pass pay onto the other class?

```
for(int i=0;i<list_of_food.size();i++) {
    food = list_of_food.get(i);
    report += food.toString();
    double totalprice_of_food = food.getQuantity() * food.getPrice();
    pay += totalprice_of_food;
    report = report + " -  "+totalprice_of_food+"\n";
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to pass it to the drinks class in order to calculate the total amount? You can return the food subtotal and the drinks subtotal to your main class and add them.

Comment: Why can't you do it? What is stopping you? What part of the code is trying to "pass" it?

Comment: There is some code missing to understand the whole picture: how does this for loop relates to the FoodOrdering class and DrinkOrdering class ? where is pay variable declared?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to pass the variable to another class.

Create 3 Classes :

```
FoodOrder 
DrinksOrder 
FinalBil 

FinalBill will call your FoodOrder and DrinksOrder both to fetch the individual amount 
and calculate the Total-Bill amount.
```

Create your design like below :

```
Class FoodOrder {
    public double calculateFoodBill(){
        // Calculate and return the food bill amount
    }
}

Class DrinksOrder {
    public double calculateDrinksBill(){
        // Calculate and return the drinks bill amount
    }
}

Class FinalBill {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        FoodOrder fo   = new FoodOrder ();
        DrinksOrder do = new DrinksOrder ();

        double foodTotal   = fo.calculateFoodBill();
        double drinksTotal = do.calculateDrinksBill();

        double totalBillAmount = foodTotal + foodTotal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variables from one class to another class via class constructors..
(I hope you you are known to constructors, If not then check out on youtube.)
Happy to Help  :)